# Html5 Audio tag - having play() and pause() together in a function

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a slotmachine game. I have a problem with play() and pause() the audio with.

### javascript function for spin

```
function spin(){
//This is to play the music each time the spin() function called
document.getElementById('myMusicFile').play();
</* spin start code ... reel animations display*/>
// the below code is used to stop the audio after 4sec of spinning
setTimeout(function(){ 
     document.getElementById('myMusicFile').pause();
}, 4000);
}
```

### HTML Audio tag is:

```
<audio id="myMusicFile" preload="auto" autobuffer loop="loop"> 
  <source src="music/reel.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /> 
  <source src="music/reel.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /> 
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

This  works fine in Google Chrome. But in Firefox it plays for every alternate spin. In safari little odd.. sometimes it plays full 4sec..and sometimes it stops in between and same in IPhone safari browser.

In firefox and safari.. if I try with play and pause as buttons with the functions play() and pause() are working fine.

So, there is some problem while doing play() and pause() together for spin button. 
Please suggest me any way to solve this issue! or provide me some working samples or resources to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use some flag. Up your flag when you start playing. Don't start again if your flag is already up. And down it when you stop/pause. Any boolean variable can work.